# Docker: Multiple Compositions

Tags: docker

I've seen many examples of Docker compose and that makes perfect sense to me, but all bundle their frontend and backend as separate containers on the same composition. In my use case I've developed a backend (in Django) and a frontend (in React) for a particular application. However, I want to be able to allow my backend API to be consumed by other client applications down the road, and thus I'd like to isolate them from one another.

Essentially, I envision it looking something like this. I would have a docker-compose file for my backend, which would consist of a PostgreSQL container and a webserver (Apache) container with a volume to my source code. Not going to get into implementation details but because containers in the same composition exist on the same network I can refer to the DB in the source code using the alias in the file. That is one environment with 2 containers.

On my frontend and any other future client applications that consume the backend, I would have a webserver (Apache) container to serve the compiled static build of the React source. That of course exists in it's own environement, so my question is like how do I converge the two such that I can refer to the backend alias in my base url (axios, fetch, etc.) How do you ship both "environments" to a registry and then deploy from that registry such that they can continue to communicate across?

I feel like I'm probably missing the mark on how the Docker architecture works at large but to my knowledge there is a default network and Docker will execute the composition and run it on the default network unless otherwise specified or if it's already in use. However, two separate compositions are two separate networks, no? I'd very much appreciate a lesson on the semantics, and thank you in advance.

Comment: Ok so I'm guessing you specify a network to give these applications visibility to one another and isolation from the rest?

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of ways to get multiple Compose files to connect together.  The easiest is just to declare that one project's default network is the other's:

```yaml
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: other_default
```

(`docker network ls` will tell you the actual name once you've started the other Compose project.)  This is also suggested in the Docker [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#use-a-pre-existing-network) documentation.

An important architectural point is that your browser application will never be able to use the Docker hostnames.  Your `fetch()` call runs in the browser, not in Docker, and so it needs to reach a published port.  The best way to set this up is to have the Apache server that's serving the built UI code also [run a reverse proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html), so that you can use a same-server relative URL `/api/...` to reach the backend.  The Apache `ProxyPass` directive would be able to use the Docker-internal hostnames.

You also mention "volume with your source code".  This is not a Docker best practice.  It's frequently used to make Docker simulate a local development environment, but it's not how you want to deploy or run your code in production.  The Docker image should be self-contained, and your `docker-compose.yml` generally shouldn't need `volumes:` or a `command:`.

A skeleton layout for what you're proposing could look like:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  backend:
    image: my/backend
    environment:
      PGHOST: db
    # No ports: (not directly exposed) (but it could be)
    # No volumes: or command: (use what's in the image)
volumes:
  pgdata:
```

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  frontend:
    image: my/frontend
    environment:
      BACKEND_URL: http://backend:3000
    ports:
      - 8080:80
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: backend_default
```

Comment: I mean the volume is just for development, obviously in production I'll create a Dockerfile with a COPY for the source.

Comment: Also if you specify a network that doesn't exist will Docker automatically create it or do you have to create it ahead of time? How does this networking work in production when you deploy?

Comment: If you specify an [`external:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external-1) network, it must already exist.  In my last example the first `docker-compose.yml` with the backend will create it.